# Displaying an HTML page sent by the server after an AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am asking this question after searching all over the Internet. I do this a lot with a JEE server and jsps. I am trying with with Node and JQuery and having a hard time getting it to work. I have a form that grabs an input, I do an Ajax post to the server and the server responds by rendering a view based on the input. Seems to me that I should not have to worry about a popup attached to a click event on the client. For the life of me I cannot display the page sent by the server in response to the input. Am I missing something here? Any pearl of wisdom on this use case would be greatly appreciated. I tried some related examples and they don't seen to work. Here is the code. Upon return from the server the HTML is not rendered. I just add the javascript that does the AJAX post and processes the response from the server.

```
script.
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#dialog").dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       modal: true,
       title: "Details",
       buttons: {
           Close: function () {
               $(this).dialog('close');
           }
       }
     });
     $("#OK").click(function() {
        var org = $("#name").val();
        if (org == '' ){
           alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
        } else {
           alert("about to post "+org);
           $.post("/repost", 
              {name: org})
              .done(function(data) {
                 alert(data);
                 $("#dialog").html(data);
                 $("#dialog").dialog("open");
              });
           $("#form")[0].reset();
        } 
     });
     $("#cancel").click(function() {
         $("#form").dialog("close"); // To close the form
     });
  });
```

Server code:

```
app.post('/repost', function(req, res) {
 console.log("We are called with ", req.body);
 res.render('reposub.jade', {org:req.body.name, title: 'Express' });});
```

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you're looking for help with `$.post`:

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( tx_response ) {
  //console.dir(tx_reponse) -- does this have ususal stuff like _data_ and _status_? Or is is a raw HTML response?
    if (/* some condition like: tx_response.status === 200 */) {
    // if the html is a template, and not a redirect to a new url:
      $('.result').html(tx_response.data)
    // redirect:
    window.location.href = tx_response.data
//...
});
```

If it is neither a redirect nor a template, but rather a whole new http reply with HTML that the client should load, I think you can use `document.write` but .. this could be engineered better in that case. Arguably the response should be at most a redirect URL, or a template.

Comment: code on the server: `app.post('/repost', function(req, res) {
     console.log("We are called with ", req.body);
     res.render('reposub.jade', {org:req.body.name, title: 'Express' });
});`

Comment: You might go back and tag your question express, as well. :) Umm, that returns a whole page. So `document.write(tx_response.data)` would render that (just check the `console.dir(tx_response)` if you run into problems) .. and you might consider returning only a template and rendering it in the view, rather than the whole page from the server.

Comment: Thanks will tag as express. The paradigm I was looking after was similar to the one we have with Java application servers. There should be a classic way to do this. 1. I post a data to the server 2. The server processes the data 3. The server renders a template in response to the data and sends it to the client. Not sure if Express was designed with that in mind.

Comment: yea so.. did you try what I suggested? That should be the answer.

Comment: I tried what you had in your first response and it did not work. I will try the document.write and where it takes me. I was also trying to avoid opening a new window and writing to it as this is pretty much a popup that most browsers block, requiring people to specifically allow them.

Comment: `document.write` was in my first response :) I guess you just wanted it all done for you, sorry I didnt do that, I'm not developing express at the moment so I didn't have a model handy to go by

Comment: I got a workaround opening a window with the right URL                     `window.open('https://mypath?name='+org, 'newwindow',"toolbar=no,menubar=no,top=300,left=500,height=800,width=1024");` instead of doing the post and processing the server response. I did not change anything on the server. the window.open did what I attempted to do. This is a pretty lame and an ugly work around that I tried to avoid because of popup restrictions and UX considerations. This is a big turn off for jquery. Even if there is a solution it is still bad that it is counterintuitive. I need to open a bug report.

Comment: Well, I take back that I did not change the server. I changed the server to accept a GET in addition to the POST I could do. Basically added an app.get() with the same code as the app.post().

Comment: Forget about all I said in tha last 3 comments. This was a user error. I am able to habve the page rendered by using the $.htm(data) call which I was using unsuccessfully. I did not have a container for the data. I created a div and used the div to display the content and it worked. So essentially I did a    `$("div.listcontainer").html(data);` and that took care of it, I defined the div in the body section as div.clistcontainer (I am using Jade) and it rendered as `<div class=listcontainer" />` Thanks for the help anyway. Solved!

Comment: Please delete your question fi you aren't going to mark mine as the solution then. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to roberto tomás answer, also make sure your server has CORS support enabled. This is particular useful when:

1. developing something in local, that is not served by a webserver;
2. whenever your frontend is not located on the same host (thus ip and port combination) of your backend (in your case your nodejs app)

Useful resources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
- https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: It is on the same domain. The server responds by doing a res.render(), the html comes across fine. I just cannot display it.

Answer (score 0):

So in my case, I had to have a div element that I can run the html method against. So with a div element created in the body of my html page, I was able to do a $("div.listcontainer").html(data); and my page displayed fine.